# why is the try catch block not working correctly with errors

Tags: powershell

I am trying to capture errors in a meaningful way, as thats my habit, and when it comes to this block of code, i am not getting the result/output im hoping for:

```
Unblock-File $dll1 -Verbose 4>&1

Add-Type -Path $dll1
Add-Type -Path $dll2
```

I get this output:

> ERROR! Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Users\Documents\DLLS\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515) At C:\Users\Documents\test.ps1:7 char:2
>   +     Add-Type -Path $dll1
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ at , C:\Users\Documents\test.ps1: line 7
>
> This error typically occurs when files are downloaded from a
>   potentially untrusted source and therefore are blocked.
>
> Attempting to Unblock file(s)...
>
> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Unblock-File" on target
>   "C:\Users\Documents\DLLS\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll".
>
> ERROR! Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Users\Documents\DLLS\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515) At C:\Users\Documents\test.ps1:24 char:2
>   +     Add-Type -Path $dll1
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ at , C:\Users\Documents\test.ps1: line 24

After the VERBOSE, this shouldn't error out again:

> ERROR! Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Users\Documents\DLLS\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515) At C:\Users\Documents\test.ps1:24 char:2 +
>   Add-Type -Path $dll1 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ at ,
>   C:\Users\Documents\test.ps1: line 24

instead, now that the file is unblocked, the assembly should be loaded with the second attempt in this 2nd try block. `Add-Type -Path $dll1`. so why is it outputting the error once again? it should output it for the second dll, because that one has yet to be unblocked, but instead it still complains about dll1. I can see that dll1 file was truly unblocked.

Here is my full code:

```
$dllPath = "C:\Users\Documents\DLLS"

$dll1 = "$dllPath\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll"
$dll2 = "$dllPath\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.dll"

try {
    Add-Type -Path $dll1
    Add-Type -Path $dll2
}
catch {
    if ($error[0].tostring().contains("Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"))
    {
        write-host "`r`nERROR! $($error[0])`r`n$($error[0].InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)`r`n$($error[0].ScriptStackTrace)" -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor black
        write-host "`r`nThis error typically occurs when files are downloaded from a potentially untrusted source and therefore are blocked." -foregroundcolor magenta -backgroundcolor black
        write-host "`r`n Attempting to Unblock file(s)...`r`n" -foregroundcolor cyan -backgroundcolor black

        $error.clear()

        try {
            #Get-ChildItem -Path $dllPath\*.* -Filter *.dll | Unblock-File

            Unblock-File $dll1 -Verbose 4>&1

            Add-Type -Path $dll1
            Add-Type -Path $dll2
        }
        catch {
            write-host "`r`nERROR! $($error[0])`r`n$($error[0].InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)`r`n$($error[0].ScriptStackTrace)" -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor black
        }
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "`r`nERROR! $($error[0])`r`n$($error[0].InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)`r`n$($error[0].ScriptStackTrace)" -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor black
    }
}
```

Comment: [1] have you tried unblocking those files from file explorer? ///// [2] are you sure that you have all the dependencies for those files? i suspect that they have more than just those two files ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey 1. Yep, but I want this to be dynamic, so that if future dll files are added the script handles them. 2. Yep. If I launch another powershell session, the error disappears.

Comment: you may want to add that info to your Question. [*grin*] given that info, it seems you are seeing a timing problem. you may need to add a loop to add a delay. a simple `Start-Sleep` would pause the script, so you would need to using something like the stopwatch stuff.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey time pause...interesting. but wouldnt that just pause temporarily then still throw out the error again? I mean it's just delaying the time, it has to do something with the try catch, I just cant put my finger on it

Comment: i don't have any way to test it ... but what i understand of the description makes it look like a timing problem. if that aint it ... then i am stuck. i will go back to lurking on this Question ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey basically the code works just fine except I'm annoyed about the output of the second try catch block. Since the file was unblocked the first time the error was thrown, there shouldn't be a second error thrown, at least the same one.

Comment: i understand ... and am at a loss for any way to understand it, much less deal with it. good luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of code to the top suppress error notifications.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
```

Comment: doesnt change anything. this is is because im actually intending to write the errors anyways, but it shouldnt be writing the error again if the assembly was already loaded in the 2nd try block.